# Very simple javascript ocr on black text white background

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ocr

I have a super simple need of OCR.

My application allows creating image from text. Its very simple. People choose a font face, bold or not, and size.

So they get outputs like this, ignoring the border:

[image]

I wanted to create a very simple OCR to read these. I thought of this approach:

In the same way I generate an image for the message. I should generate an image for each character. Then I go through and try to match each character image to the black occourances in the canvas. Is this right approach?

The method I use to draw element to image is this copy paste example here: [MDN :: Drawing DOM objects into a canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas)

Comment: OCR is not simple (and is not all that effective). Why not just remember the message that you initially drew?

Comment: Thanks @markE thats a good point to remember. But the thing is I made a browser addon and this is a social share feature, so when people are discovering other peoples images made with my addon they are not able to select the text. :(

Comment: If you want to proceed with doing it by OCR (which is far from good solution, as @markE wrote), look for OCR javascript library - for example: http://antimatter15.com/ocrad.js/demo.html

Comment: Thanks @piotrwest. For simplicity I can disallow the different fonts and sizes, as it is right now. Its just Arial at bold and size 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, another couple of tries...

**Another method that's simpler than OCR**: use **Steganography** to embed the text message as part of the image itself. Here's a script that uses the alpha channel of an image to store text: http://www.peter-eigenschink.at/projects/steganographyjs/index.html

**You can try this "home brewed" OCR solution**...but I have doubts about its effectiveness.

1. Use the clipping form of `context.drawImage` to draw just the message-text area of your image on the canvas.
2. Use `context.getImageData` to grab the pixel information.
3. Examine each vertical column starting from the left until you find an opaque pixel (this is the left side of the first letter).
4. Continue examining each vertical column until you find a column with all transparent pixels (this is the right side of the first letter).
5. Resize a second canvas to exactly contain the discovered letter and `drawImage` just the first letter to a second canvas.
6. Set `globalCompositeOperation='destination-out'` so that any new drawing will erase any existing drawings where the new & old overlap.
7. `fillText` the letter "A" on the second canvas.
8. Use `context.getImageData` to grab the pixel information on the second canvas.
9. Count the opaque pixels on the second canvas.
10. If the opaque pixel count is high, they you probably haven't matched the letter A, so repeat steps 5-9 with the letter B.
11. If the opaque pixel count is low, then you may have found the letter A.
12. If the opaque pixel count is medium-low, you may have found the letter A but the 2 A's are not quite aligned. Repeat steps 5-9 but offset the A in step#7 by 1 pixel horizontally or vertically. Continue offsetting the A in 1 pixel offsets and see if the opaque pixel count becomes low.
13. If step#12 doesn't produce a low pixel count, continue with the letter B,C,etc and repeat steps 5-9.

When you're done discovering the first letter, go back to step#1 and only draw the message-text with an offset that excludes the first letter.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for still thinking about me I thought everyone told me to give up and move on haha. I was going to try to keep everything 24px arial black. And just get single characters and try to do the puzzle method. I'll read this and try this thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

OCR is always complex and often inaccurate.

I hate to wave you off of a solution, but don't use OCR for your purpose

Simple and effective solution...

*Put your message in the image's file name.*

Comment: Thanks @markE! Putting into file name is great idea, but on upload to the social esrver they rename the darn file haha :(

Answer (score 1):

Solution found - GOCR.js - https://github.com/antimatter15/gocr.js/tree/d820e0651cf819e9649a837d83125724a2c1cc37

1. download gocr.js
2. decide if you want to go from WebWorker, or mainthread

#### worker

In the worker put this code:

```
importScripts(gocr.js)
GOCR(aImgData)
```

where aImgData is, take an image, load it, draw it to canvas, then send the data to the webworker. (see mainthread method)

#### mainthread

```
<script src="gocr.js">
<script>
var img = new Image()
img.onerror = function() {
    console.error('failed')
}
img.onload = function() {

    var can = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'canvas');
    can.width = img.width;
    can.height = img.height;
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d')
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
   // to use this in a worker, do ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height), then transfer the image data to the WebWorker
    var text = GOCR(can);

}
</script>
```